# Should I use "late lunch" or "a late lunch" in the following?

Tags: grammar, phrase-choice

> He walked to the kitchenette to have (a) late lunch.
>
> He had a piece of toast and a painkiller for (a) late lunch.

Should I use "late lunch" or "a late lunch"? And why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"Have **a** late lunch" is correct. The other is incorrect.

There's a set of nouns that are so common in society that we talk about them as general societal concepts, like "I saw it on *television*", "I was on *the phone* all afternoon" or "I spent a year in *prison*". They either use "the" or no article. The main meals, "breakfast", "lunch" and "dinner" are in this category, along with "tea" in the UK and Ireland. "Late lunch" is not one of these general societal concepts, so we have to follow the normal rules of English and use the article "a".

Comment: Can "late lunch" - without the article - be used to describe behavior/pattern? *He goes to the café to have late lunch.* Or *He comes in here everyday for his black coffee.*

Comment: @AIQ No to your first example sentence. I've improved my answer above, which might explain why. I'm not sure what you're asking with your second example sentence. It means he comes in here every day (<-- note the space) and buys a black coffee.

Comment: I was asking whether we can omit the articles when *late lunch* is something that someone always does, like *He drinks black tea*. It would be perfectly fine if we said "He takes his lunch late", but I am wondering if *He takes late lunch* is idiomatic language. I guess not.

Comment: If you describe someone's meal as _late_, it implies that they are eating later than they normally do, or after the time period when most people have that meal.  I agree with @AIQ that _He takes late lunch_ is not  usually idiomatic. (If a group of co-workers take staggered lunch breaks so that the office or workroom is never deserted, they might informally call the second period 'late lunch'.)

Comment: @gotube The way I see it, the intrusion of the article comes because we added a modifier to the meal; it could be any modifier ("... to have an *enormous* lunch"). I could imagine a few modifiers which could become so bound to the meal by convention as to denote a new type of meal and not need the article: "This is our favorite place to have Sunday brunch," or "The hobbits stopped to have Second Breakfast."

Comment: @AIQ It's not idiomatic for the reasons in my answer. "He drinks black tea" is used without an article not because someone always does it, but because "black tea" is a non-count noun

Comment: @AIQ This is getting a bit in to the weeds, but say your coworker John always eats lunch at 3PM.  If someone asks "Where is John?" it would be fine to reply "He's having his late lunch". Since it's established he indeed has late lunches. That may be a bit of a contrived scenario but wanted to mention.

Comment: ***“I had lunch** at "Inferno" a famous trattoria”* vs ***“I had *a* delicious lunch** *at Inferno”*. It's the adjective "late" which necessitates the article but I don't know why :)

Comment: @Mari-LouA Because "delicious lunch" isn't one of those general things (whatever they're called... where's BillJ)

Comment: I think that "a late lunch" identifies what type of lunch it was. *He went to school* (we know it's the same building he normally goes to every day but we don't know anything else) *He went to a posh school* (It's still the same institution but now we know what type of school, so we identify it by using the indefinite article – *a posh one*). If there was only one posh school in his area, we'd use the definite article "He went to *the* posh school". So, by using the indefinite article in "a late lunch" the speaker clarifies the *type* of lunch.

Answer (score 1):

As a phrase in itself, you can have late lunch at a restaurant or event, where it usually means cold food, often from the lunch menu, served after the lunch serving ends. This often can be just so the chef has a break between lunch and the evening meal.

This is not that common a phrase though. In your examples, it is not the meaning you want.

But it's not incorrect when you want to talk about late lunch - there's a difference to going somewhere which serves lunch from 12 to 5 and having 'a late lunch' at 4, and going somewhere which serves the full lunch menu from 12 to 3 and then serves late lunch from 3 to 5 and having 'late lunch' at 4.